# Calculated 'Me' to check user exist in SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, calculated-column, groups

Is it possible to check [Me] in SharePoint Calculated Columns against with a SharePoint group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible, The `[ME]` is not supported in the calculated column

For more details check [The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](http://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

As we know, calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me.

If you really need to use them, then there is a workaround that you can use:

1.Create a temporary column called "Me".

2.Create your calculated column with the formula that you need.

3.Delete the temporary column you created (Me).

For more detailed information, refer to the following articles:

http://help.share-gate.com/article/761-calculated-columns-cannot-contain-volatile-functions-like-today-and-me

https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/